# Encode a symbol python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode, encode

I have a symbol as an output  and it appears as '' when i print it. So I tried `x.encode('utf-8')` to get back the symbol, instead I get `ïƒ¼`. I looked at many examples but nothing provides a solution for this.

How do i fix this?

Comment: What encoding does your terminal / console use?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  How do i know that??

Comment: What OS are you using? What terminal or console program are you using?

Comment: And what does `print repr(x)` give you? The exact codepoint would be helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OS - Windows 7 and I am using a python IDLE version 2.7

Comment: So you are printing this in IDLE? What does `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding` print?

Comment: @MartijnPieters   repr(x) gives <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02D42368>

Comment: That is not a string, that is a regular expression match object. That is not the same object as what you are talking about in your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding print gives cp1252

Comment: @MartijnPieters well u r right..mistake i referred to different variable... It gives u'\uf0fc'
'

Comment: That is not a valid Unicode codepoint: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0fc/index.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35427/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-sangamesh-hs)

Answer (score 0):

Your console or terminal font doesn't support that codepoint; it is printing just fine otherwise.

However, your terminal is not configured to print UTF-8, so printing the UTF-8 bytes results in garbage instead.

You need to change the *font* used for your terminal or console program instead, to show that specific codepoint.

However, if the codepoint you are printing in [U+F0FC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0fc/index.htm) then no font will print that other than as a placeholder glyph. That is private-use codepoint and no common-use font will be able to display it.

In this case, you'll have to replace that codepoint with something else to represent whatever that codepoint stood for in the original data. In chat you mentioned it was a Powerpoint checkmark. Your output is limited to the [Windows 1252 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) so you need to pick a character within that standard, take the unicode codepoint for that character and replace the U+F0FC codepoints with that value.

If you were to use `•` character (hex 95 in the 1252 codepage, unicode point U+2022) for example, then you replace the private codepoint with:

```
someunicodestring.replace(u'\uf0fc', u'\u2022')
```

Comment: Is there a solution for this to test. Because this is very critical for me atleast!!